# How to set a progress for many progress-bars in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am using a RecyclerView to view many Progress Bars as a slide show and an adapter.

This my adapter class

```
    public class RecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "RecAdapter";
private ArrayList progressbars = new ArrayList<>();
private Context pcontex;
public RecAdapter(Context pcontex ,ArrayList progressbars) {
    this.progressbars = progressbars;
    this.pcontex = pcontex;
}
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progress,viewGroup,false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return progressbars.size() ;
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ProgressBar b ;
    ConstraintLayout parent;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
       b = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        parent= itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);


       } 
    }
    }
```

My MainActivity code-

```
Prog = new ArrayList<>();  b2 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar) ;
b = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);  
probitmap();

private void probitmap(){

Log.d(TAG, "probitmap: preparing bit maps");
Prog.add(b); 
Prog.add(b2);

Recycle();// this method is out of on create
}

private void  Recycle(){

Log.d(TAG, "Recycle: init recycleview");
recyclerView =findViewById(R.id.Rec);
RecAdapter Adapter = new RecAdapter(this,Prog);
recyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
        = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
```

The code is working perfectly but I need to retrieve every progress bar that is in the recycle view and set progress for each one.

I tried multiple ways but it doesn't work. Here is what I tried-

```
for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        RecAdapter.ViewHolder holder = (RecAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
        holder.b.setProgress(50);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `OnBindViewHolder` to manage each "row" generated by the recycler.

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.b.setProgress(progressbar.get(i)); //i is the position of the recycler
        viewHolder.b.setListener....
 }
```

Comment: thank you , but  setprogress method takes an integer , i did not git it :(

Comment: and why using listener , i am sorry but i am a beginner

Comment: Listener was just an example. You can handle whatever you want from there. Fill the array on your adapter with the integer values you want to pass to the progress bars; in order. If you are passing an array if progress bars you can always do: viewHolder.b.setProgress(progressbar.get(i).getProgress());